# Help with Salesforce formula

Tags: formula-field

I am having trouble getting a formula to work.

here is the criteria .....
Formula should be if Alien_Certification_Expiration__c is null or empty, return “None”
Alien_Certification_Expiration__c is > TODAY (in the future), return “Yes”
else, return “No”

I am pretty new to salesforce formulas and cant seem to get this working.  any help would be greatly appreciated

THis is the code i have

```
IF(
    ISBLANK(Alien_Certification_Expiration__c), 
    "None",
    "IF(
        Alien_Certification_Expiration__c >= TODAY()
    ), 
    'Yes',  
    'No')"
)
```

Looking to populate the field with Yes if Alien_Certification_Expiration__C date is > Today,  and a No if not

The field is showing IF(Alien_Certification_Expiration__c >= TODAY()), 'Yes',  'No' not yes or no.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour]. Please [edit] your post to include the formula code, and describe the result you expect and the result you actually get.

Comment: This question feels very familiar. Have you perhaps asked a similar question in the past week or so and then deleted it?

Comment: Nope this is my first question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have quotes where they shouldn't be. The else value can be a nested if statement:

```
IF(
    ISBLANK(Alien_Certification_Expiration__c),
    "None", 
    IF(
        Alien_Certification_Expiration__c >= TODAY(), 
        "Yes",  
        "No"
    )
)
```